# Inserting Pandas framework into SQL Server with Auto_Increment Column

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read an excel file and append(insert) data into SQL (Azure DB) existing table. The table has an auto_increment field which is handled by SQL and do not want to touch. I am trying to insert the values using this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/io.html#sql-queries
but it is generating errors.

I can query the data but cannot insert. Here is my code and error

```
SQL Table: Hello
aID Int auto_increment
Col1 Int
Col2 String

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import datetime
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};serverinformation;database;username;passwrod)
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
print('connected')

path = r'excel_file'
df= pd.read_excel(path)
//Excel file has same columns as SQL table except aID which auto_increment

    enter code here

print(df.info())
df.to_sql(
    name='Hello',  # database table name
    con=engine,
    schema= '[dbo]', 
    if_exists='append',
    index = False
)


Getting following error

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'Hello' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)"



  // and it tries to create the DB table

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

I want to know what i am doing wrong and where? Cannot seem to find the solution
```

Edit: Solution

My method was write, it was the error I was not reading it right. If you have multiple Schema than explicitly indicate the schema you want to upload the data to the table. Recheck your df and make sure it matches with the table columns.

Comment: I use sql / azure / python as well and what you do seem right. I do not explicity call the schema... maybe try this without calling out schema dbo

Comment: No worries! that is why we have a community! Just validate the answer I posted.

Comment: It created a database table and than added it. So it is working like ORM and not appending it.

Comment: Like the same table in your environment azure sql? It is not possible. How are the 2 tables called in your azure sql database? Do they have the same metadata?

Comment: The table I would like to insert the data is in Schema [DS ] and my [DBO] has meta tables. I want to insert the data in [DS] schema so that's why I am identifying it.
When I inserted the data without explicitly identifying Schema than it creates a table in [DBO] which is SQL default schema. I don't want that.

Comment: But you where identifying it to schema='dbo', shouldn't you hence apply the 'ds' schema?

Comment: I have been identifying the right schema for the data insert. Why it is not picking? Is there something I am missing from my code?

Comment: do you write 'ds' or '[ds]' in your 'actual' script?

Comment: tried both ways, when [] I get this error sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named Hello in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")

when I used ds then it gave me an error but that was for my panda framework which I did not read first. I missed one of the columns in the framework which is "Not Null". after fixing that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you should not call out the schema explicitly.

```
df.to_sql(
name='Hello',  # database table name
con=engine,
if_exists='append',
index = False
)
```